# In fatfree framework, can I format template variables without creating dictionary files?

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I want to format a variable as currency before displaying on the template. Now I know I can create a language specific dictionary file and use it to format it as currency, but is there a way to do it directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `format()` method:

```
echo $f3->format('Price: {0,number,currency}',29.90);//Price: $29.90
```

See [here](http://fatfreeframework.com/base#format) for more examples.

From within a template, the syntax would be:

```
{{'Price: {0,number,currency}',@price|format}}
```